# Lax-Milgram on Parabolic Equation 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega=(0,\pi)\times(0,\pi)$and the problem

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
      \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\Delta u+u_{x}-u=t\sin(x+y)
&
(0,1)\times \Omega \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}+u=1 
& 
(0,1)\times \partial \Omega \\
u(0,x)=1& \Omega \end{array} \right. $$

I was asked to find the variational form and to prove that this problem has an unique solution. I found the variational form:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(u(t),v)+\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \nabla v-\int_{\partial{\Omega}}v+\int_{\partial{\Omega}}uv+\int_{\Omega}u_{x}v-\int_{\Omega}uv=\int_{\Omega}t\sin(x+y)v,$$where $v\in H^{1}_{0}$. How can I prove the coercitivity? Can you give me some suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I have edited your post to improve readability. Take a look at how to typeset a system of equations in MathJax for further details by clicking "Edit", you can see the code from there. Enjoy your stay on our site!

Comment: I understand, I think, that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ is the partial derivative in the direction of the surface normal but what is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial u}$?  Did you mean $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$?

Comment: Thank you!!i edited.The first one is the normal derivative